# Date format for committerdate on git for-each-ref

Tags: git

I'm using this to get a list of stale branches in our repo:

`git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' refs/remotes --format='"%(refname)",%(committerdate),"%(authorname)"' > branches.csv`

But the ***committerdate*** comes out like this:
`Thu Jan 7 15:45:35 2021 -0700`

Can I make it come out like this instead?
`Jan 7 2021 15:45:35 -0700`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' refs/remotes --format='"%(refname)",%(committerdate:iso),"%(authorname)"' > branches.csv`

Shows like this (easier sorted datetime)
`2021-01-07 15:45:35 -0700`

Works perfectly but I do not like the TZ being displayed, have to take that out with a text editor before opening in Excel. ;-)

Comment: How can I get it to print in UTC (or local) rather than showing the TZ offsets?